# How should I apply if-else condition to display different menu to people with different user roles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, global-variables, document-ready

I've two user roles defines i.e.

**1 : roleId for Admin user and 2: roleId for normal user**

The logic I tried has been written in two javascript code files(.js files as follows):

**First file : prj.js**

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://prj.firebaseio.com");
var loggedInUser = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    authData=ref.getAuth();

    if(authData == null){
        //TODO find an elegant way to manage authorization 
    //  window.location = "../index.html";
    }else{
        ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot){
            $( "span.user-name").html(snapshot.val().displayName);  
            loggedInUser.displayName = snapshot.val().displayName;
            loggedInUser.roleId = snapshot.val().roleId;
        });         
    }
});
```

**Second file : navigation.js**

```
appraisalMenuHTML = '       <li class="{{appraisal}}" class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle appraisal"'
    +'          data-toggle="dropdown"  href="/prj/pages/appraisal/appraisalDashboard.html"><span id="appraisal"> Appraisal</span></a>'
    +'          <ul class="dropdown-menu">'
    +'              <li><a href="/prj/pages/appraisal/appraisalDashboard.html">Submit review </a></li>'
    +       ' </ul></li>';

userOptionsHTML = ' <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">'
    +'      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle"'
    +'          data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><img src="/prj/images/settings.png"/></a>'
    +'          <ul class="dropdown-menu">'
    +'              <li><a href="/prj/pages/appraisal/reports.html"> Appraisal</a></li>'
    +'          </ul>'
    +       '</li>'
    +'      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle user-name"'
    +'          data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="user-name"></span><span class="caret"></span></a>'
    +'          <ul class="dropdown-menu">'
    +'              <li><a href="/prj/pages/profile.html"> Profile</a></li>'
    +'              <li><a href="/prj/index.html"> Logout</a></li>'
    +'          </ul>'
    +       '</li>'
    +'  </ul>';



navHTML = 
    '<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">'
    +'<div class="container-fluid">'
    +'<div class="navbar-header">'
    +'  <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"'
    +'      data-target="#securedNavbar">'
    +'      <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span'
    +'          class="icon-bar"></span>'+' </button>'+'</div>'+'<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="securedNavbar">'
    +'  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">'
    +'      <li class="{{feeds}}"><a href="/prj/pages/feeds.html"><img src="/prj/images/darpan-logo.png" height="20px" /> Home</a></li>'
    +'      <li class="{{projects}}" class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle projects"'
    +'   data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="projects">Projects</span></a>'
    +'          <ul class="dropdown-menu">'
    +'              <li><a href="/prj/pages/project/projectList.html">List</a></li>'
    +'              <li><a href="/prj/pages/project/createNewProject.html">Add new project</a></li>'
    +'          </ul>'
    +'      </li>'
    +'      <li class="{{training}}"><a href="#">Training</a></li>'

    + appraisalMenuHTML

    +'      <li class="{{recruitment}}"><a href="#">Recruitment</a></li>'
    +'      <li class="{{users}}" class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle users"'
    +'      data-toggle="dropdown" href="/prj/pages/user/userList.html"><span class="users">Users</span></a>'
    +'          <ul class="dropdown-menu">'
    +'              <li><a href="/prj/pages/user/userList.html">List</a></li>'
    +'              <li><a href="/prj/pages/user/createNewUser.html">Add new user</a></li>'
    +'          </ul>'
    +'      </li>'
    +'  </ul>'

    + userOptionsHTML

    +'</div>'
    +'</div>'
    +'</nav>';
    function darpanNav(selectedTab){
    alert('Object is : '+loggedInUser.toString());  
    theCompiledTemplate = navHTML.replace("{{"+selectedTab+"}}", "active")
    newRow = $("#nav-div").html(theCompiledTemplate);
}
```

HTML file is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
.
.
.
.
.
.

<script src="../js/prj.js"></script>

    <script src="/prj/js/navigation.js"></script>

    <script>
    darpanNav("feeds");

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note :** All the necessary libraries and files have been included. So don't worry about it.

Now what I want to achieve is apply if-else condition on the content of variable `navHTML` from file `navigation.js` based on user roles. That is if roleId is 2 then I don't want to display content of `appraisalMenuHTML` and if it is 1 display it.

How should I achieve this?

The issue I'm facing in applying condition od `newHTML` is I'm not able to access modified global variable `loggedInUser` values. This is the main obstacle in my task.

Somebody please help me.

Comment: can you please create a plunker or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in prj.js, `loggedInUser` seems to belong to global scope, so you should be able to access it in navigation.js since it is invoked after prj.js. Note however it is not good practice to have anything in global scope.

Unless you have a good reason to create your template from javascript files (if you use React.js for instance) you should place that in actual html files, and make the logic thanks to a template engine like [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/).